# Как сделать что бы бот ожидал пока пользователь прикрепит файл, а потом сохранит его в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Нужно сделать так, что бы бот ожидал на протяжении 60 секунд пока пользователь отправит картинку. После чего бот должен ее сохранить в корневую папку с файлом. Библиотека discord.py

```
for attach in mag5.attachments:
        await attach.save(f"./{message.author.id}.png")
```

Вот код сохранения файла, он будет работать если внедрить в структуру on_message. Но мне нужно сделать что бы бот ожидал, пока пользователь отправит файл, а потом эта часть кода сделает свое дело, и как это сделать я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Использование: !test `ссылка на сообщение`, если есть вложения, он сохранит их в main path

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx: commands.Context, message_url: str)
    splited_url = message_url.split("/")
    guild_id = int(splited_url[4])
    channel_id = int(splited_url[5])
    message_id = int(splited_url[6])
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    msg = await discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id=channel_id).fetch_message(message_id)
    attachments = msg.attachments
    if attachments:
        new_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id=new_channel)
        for attachment in attachments:
            await attachment.save(f"{msg.author.id}.png")
```